# Slack - how to optimise linked site for multilingual unfurling?

Tags: multilingual, facebook-opengraph, slack, slack-api

Does Slack provide any particular support for multilingual links pasted into a Slack discussion? This is in terms of when it is discovering the OpenGraph data from the linked page.

For example, Facebook supports this via the `og:locale` and `og:locale:alternate` tags and will then send a 'X-Facebook-Locale' header, per the description here: http://qnimate.com/open-graph-protocol-in-facebook/

Slack [does support OpenGraph](https://medium.com/slack-developer-blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-unfurling-but-were-afraid-to-ask-or-how-to-make-your-e64b4bb9254) when introspecting pages, but I am not sure whether it goes as far as trying to deal with the same page that might be in multiple languages.

Does Slack provide any equivalent support? I did look into the documentation, but could not find any references to this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but its still pretty unclear from your description. I think what you are actually asking is whether Slack will automatically unfurl links for multiple languages based on their OG locale meta tags.

Comment: Slack does support OG meta tags in general when unfurling tags, not sure about the locale tag though. But its should be really easy to test if you have such a link.

Comment: Updated the question. It is to see if the Slack will try to find the different language versions of the same page, so that the link preview is displayed in the appropriate language.